Interporating with C embedded struct ("inheritance") in C++
I'm working on a C++ program depends on a C library that uses the "struct embedding" trick to simulate inheritance (of data storage, not behaviour), similar to the Parent and Child structs in the example below.
When I have a pointer to one of the children (e.g. ChildA *), I can't pass it to a function that expects a Parent * without an explicit cast.
With regular C++ inheritance, such an up-cast is unnecessary/implied. Is there a way to make it work similarly with this C pseudo-inheritence?

If that's possible, is it even advisable?
And if not, is that &child->base alternative preferable over the cast?

Here's a concrete example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

struct Parent {
    int id;
};

struct ChildA {
    struct Parent base; // Simulates inheritance
    int a;
};

struct ChildB {
    struct Parent base;
    int b;
};

struct ChildC {
    struct Parent base;
    int c;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Example objects of different types
    struct ChildA a = { .base = { .id = 1 }, .a = 1 };
    struct ChildB b = { .base = { .id = 2 }, .b = 2 };
    struct ChildC c = { .base = { .id = 3 }, .c = 3 };
    
    struct ChildA *pointer_to_a = &a;
    struct ChildB *pointer_to_b = &b;
    struct ChildC *pointer_to_c = &c;
    
    // Heterogeneous objects can be psuedo up-casted and held in a  container
    vector<struct Parent *> v{
        // Can this up-cast be made implicit, like it is for regular C++ classes?
        reinterpret_cast<struct Parent *>(pointer_to_a),
        reinterpret_cast<struct Parent *>(pointer_to_b),
        reinterpret_cast<struct Parent *>(pointer_to_c),
    };
    
    // Is this better than the cast?
    vector<struct Parent *> v2{
        &pointer_to_a->base,
        &pointer_to_b->base,
        &pointer_to_c->base,
    };
    
    // Example of homogeneous usage of the common "base"
    // parts of the various objects
    for (auto &p : v) {
        cout << p->id << endl;
    }
}


No, it's not advisable.  Why don't you just use inheritance instead of encapsulation?

@TimRoberts Ah I omitted a key detail: the library in question is written in C

No, it is not advisable, unless you enjoy dealing with implications of undefined behaviour.    If your code is intended to be used from C++, just use inheritance that is part of the language.    If your code is intended to be used from C, instead of using casts, access the named "embedded" member.

@Peter Thanks for the input. I don't think this is UB in C (source), is this UB in C++? And by 'access the named "embedded" member"', are you revering to the &pointer_to_a->base variant?

It is undefined behaviour in C++ (although I suppose language lawyers might mention specific circumstances where it isn't). That link makes some very specific assumptions - which, if not met, would also introduce undefined behaviour in C.  Potential for UB aside, explicit type conversions are easy to misuse, so better avoided, and in this case, you're achieving nothing more than accessing the named member.  If the class is maintained (e.g. to add other members to the "child" classes) it is also easy to introduce UB in code that uses the cast, which using a named member avoids.

I'd consider accessing a library in a different language to be I/O, and a good principle for that is to convert everything to an internal representation on input, and keep it like that until output. So use C++ inheritance, only convert to and from C structs when necessary.

What would be the example usage of your library in the C code? Probably you should consider @JohnBayko comment and convert your data into some POD whenever it's supposed to be used by C.

It is most definitely not UB in C++ to cast a pointer of a struct to its first member if the struct is standard-layout, which it has to be because it's from a C library. However, there is no automatic way of doing it, so you might as well write the member access.

@Peter Let me give the concrete example, on this line I cast paramsNode->block up to a pm_node * (the base type) so I can recursively call translate(), which then discriminates its "type" and downcasts down to pm_block_parameter_node *. If I use &paramsNode->block.base instead of the first cast, I'll still need a cast eventually anyway. Would that second cast be safe? It assumes that there's more to to the object than just the base it starts with

@JohnBayko I generally agree, and I'm a huge proponent of that idea, but this is a performance and memory critical section that we want to minimize allocating/copying. Plus, this C library implements some nice memory optimizations for us, like object pooling and an arena allocator, that I wouldn't want to recreate (and frankly, couldn't do as well myself)

@pptaszni This is the code in question: https://github.com/Shopify/sorbet/blob/prism/parser/prism/Translator.cc#L10

@PasserBy Does that cast work both ways? See my comment to Peter above

I guess you won't like it but, could class "wrappers" / kind of duplicates be an option?
Something like
class P_class{
  public:
  struct Parent base;
  P_class(struct Parent p):base(p){};
};
class A_class : public P_class{
  public:
  int *a;
  A_class(struct ChildA *c_a) : P_class(c_a->base),a(&(c_a->a)){};
};
//...
// then you can use classes (maybe directly from a, b & c)
    A_class points_to_a(pointer_to_a);
    B_class points_to_b(pointer_to_b);
    C_class points_to_c(pointer_to_c);
//  ...
//  BTW, I guess v2 only had the Parent contents...

    vector<P_class*> v3{
      &points_to_a, &points_to_b, &points_to_c
    };

?

Considering your comment, you don't mind having a couple of pointers per child (object), so having an intermediate (pointers) class is OK
But you "have over 150 child types."
So, maybe one wrapper to rule them all children could do? Something like :
class P_class{
    public:
    struct Parent *base;
    P_class(struct Parent *p):base(p){cout<<"Impl P with "<<base->id<<endl;};
    int id(){return this->base->id;};
};
template <typename sub_struct>
class Children_s : public P_class{
    public:
    sub_struct *obj;// the child struct
    Children_s(sub_struct* ss):obj(ss), P_class(&ss->base){};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Example objects of different types
    struct ChildA a = { .base = { .id = 1 }, .a = 6 };
    struct ChildB b = { .base = { .id = 2 }, .b = 7 };
    struct ChildC c = { .base = { .id = 3 }, .c = 8 };
    
    struct ChildA *pointer_to_a = &a;
    struct ChildB *pointer_to_b = &b;
    struct ChildC *pointer_to_c = &c;

    Children_s<ChildA>* obj_a = new Children_s<ChildA>(&a);
    Children_s<ChildB> obj_b (&b);
    Children_s<ChildC>* obj_c = new Children_s<ChildC>(&c);
    
    vector<P_class*> v3{obj_a, &obj_b};
    v3.push_back(obj_c )   ;
    
    for(auto &p: v3){
        cout<<p->id() /* p->base->id */<<endl;
    }    
    
    // vector<shared_ptr<P_class>> v4 {shared_ptr<P_class>(obj_a),shared_ptr<P_class>(&obj_b)};


This is a good answer for when there's only a few cases, but unfortunately, I have over 150 child types. I could code-gen the wrappers, but they're going to be quite unwieldy

Updated the answer with a tempale based wrapper then
(only 1 needed for your >150 children)

As far as C++ is concerned, ChildA is not at all related to Parent, so the only cast that converts between ChildA* and Parent* is a reinterpret_cast.
However, you can implement auto ChildA::operator Parent*() { return &base; } (or C++23 template <typename THIS> auto ChildA::operator Parent*(THIS&& this) { return &this->base; }). This works because unlike ChildA*, ChildA itself is a user-defined-type with user-defined conversion operators.
BTW, vector<struct Parent *> makes no sense. std::vector<> is C++-only, and then the struct is redundant.

"However, you can implement" Do you think doing so would be advisable? Up-side: marginally cleaner code. Downside: hidden casts, which although they should always succeed, are now implicit and harder to discover

@Alexander: Advisable would be to wrap the entire C library in a C++ interface. The compatibility with C is intended for this use; not to mix the two at a fine-grained level.

Funny enough, that's kind of what I'm doing, by translating this new parser API into the AST node types of the parser it's replacing (which are regular C++ classes). I'm encountering these casts in the process of implementing that translation layer.
